# Website looks different on iphone and samsung

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive

I added this meta tag

`meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width`

but it didn't help me. I don't know how to fix the problem

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After doing [more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read the ['How to Ask a good question'](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Comment: the style of your question seems like asking to a colleague nearby who can directly view your screen. Please follow the hints by @AdamKosmala

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. However, here is something you could try:

If the resolutions of the devices are different they may appear a bit differently. Do not use fixed units such as pixels for width of containers,etc. Instead use percentages.

Also the exact meta tag would be `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` and should be placed within the `<head>` tag